# Is the deafult server (e.g., Webrick) used when running tests in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, webserver

when running functional and integration tests for a rails app which rails server is used during the execution of the tests? Is the default rails server used or not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to figure this out by running the test?

Comment: What test engine are you using?  For example, I use RSpec and Spork, so when I fire-up a test, it outputs that it's running on a Spork server.

Comment: @Zane, when I run the tests with the rake command, the results don't show which server is running.

Comment: @keruilin, Could I use other server such as Thin, Unicorn or Puma with RSpec? Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 2):

Rails' built-in functional and integration tests run with mocked web requests, so there is no web server serving the requests. (see lib/action_controller/test_case.rb in actionpack)

Some Rails testing frameworks (notably Capybara) use real rack servers when running (Capybara defaults to using Thin)